# Restrict JQuery datepicker to 1 every other week (biweekly)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to create a date picker that restricts dates to every other Monday. Options would look like:

Tuesday May 1st
Tuesday May 15th
Tuesday May 29th
and so on....

here's where I've started
https://jsfiddle.net/mzdoherty/wscf84a3/

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day != 1), ''];
  }
});
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution I'm happy with, so for posterity sake:
https://jsfiddle.net/mzdoherty/wscf84a3/

```
var d = new Date("5/5/2018"); // start date
var today = new Date();

while(d<today){
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 14); // set first occurence after today
}

var enableDays = [];

for (i = 0; i < 52; i++) { // gave dates for a year

  var dateString = d.getDate() + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getFullYear(); //formate

  enableDays.push(dateString);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 14);
}

function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
  var sdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('d-m-yy', date)
  if ($.inArray(sdate, enableDays) != -1) {
    return [true];
  }
  return [false];
}


$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays
});
```